# Finding $\int_{-2}^8xf(x)dx$ given $\int_{-2}^8f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a continuous function $f:[-2,8]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which is true that $f(6-x)=f(x)\forall x\in[-2,8]$. Let:
$$\int_{-2}^8f(x)dx=10$$ Now, I want to find the: 
$$\int_{-2}^8xf(x)dx$$
I am thinking of using both the methods of u-substitution and integration by parts, but I need some help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the substitution $w=6-x$, we obtain

\begin{aligned}
\int_{-2}^8xf(x)dx&=\int_{-2}^8(6-(6-x))f(6-(6-x))dx\\\\
&=-\int_{8}^{-2}(6-w)f(6-w)dw\\\\
&=\int_{-2}^{8}(6-w)f(6-w)dw\\\\
&=\int_{-2}^{8}(6-w)f(w)dw\\\\
&=6\int_{-2}^{8}f(w)dw-\int_{-2}^{8}wf(w)dw\\\\
&=60-\int_{-2}^{8}xf(x)dx
\end{aligned}
and thus
$$2\int_{-2}^{8}xf(x)dx=60$$
i.e.
$$\int_{-2}^{8}xf(x)dx=30.$$

Answer (score 27):

Here's a cute trick.

*If the problem is well-posed*, then the solution must be independent of $f$. Therefore, you can take
$$
f(x)\equiv1
$$
which is consistent with the hypotheses, and calculate
$$
\int_{-2}^8x\ \mathrm dx\equiv 30
$$

Easy peasy!

Comment: That is so cool! I have a question: how do you know exactly if the answer is independent of $f(x)$? _If the problem is well-posed_ seems like a very vague metric to me. Thanks! :)

Comment: @GaurangTandon Well, the problem may be ill-posed (say, because of a typo, or because your professor is evil). The method here is convenient as a cross-check, or in a multiple choice test. Otherwise you'll have to work harder (as in the other answers). I just wanted to show a trick that will produce the "correct answer" as easily as possible, provided an answer exists at all.

Comment: I had to upvote this, as actually, realizing this shows you understand how mathematics work :-)

Answer (score 9):

You're given:
$$I=\int_{-2}^8xf(x)dx$$

Use the $a+b-x$ property on this definite integral to get:

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-2}^8 (6-x)\cdot f(6-x)dx
\\
&=\int_{-2}^8 (6-x)\cdot f(x)dx \tag{$\because f(6-x)=f(x)$ given}
\\
&=6\int_{-2}^8f(x)-I
\end{align}$$

and you can solve it from here.

Comment: More surprises from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/290189

Comment: My favorite is [tooltip text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13259/290189), since sometimes you need to [put explations on long lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2644983/290189).  The font and color tables can be a quick reference.

Comment: @GaurangTandon As you ask about formatting, I would never use `\because` and `\therefore` in textual proofs. They are intended for automated proofs and proof verification, not for human-readable texts. This would ultimately solve your formatting issue :-)

Comment: @GaurangTandon Well, `\because` _is_ the thing you were using at high school, but this usage itself is wrong. This over-symbolism make things cluttered and difficult to read. I would omit the parenthesis completely, and write after the displayed equation something like: "where we used the hypothesis $f(6-x)=f(x)$."

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yes, more verbose is correct of course. Mathematics is dense enough on itself already.

Answer (score 2):

> Note the following formula we always have,
>   $$\color{red}{\int_a^bg(x)dx= \int_a^bg(a+b-x)dx}$$

Then with $a=-2,~b=8$ and given that $f(x) = f(6-x) $ we get $$I= \int_{-2}^8 xf(x)dx= \int_{-2}^8 (6-x)f(6-x)dx=6\int_{-2}^8 f(x)dx-\int_{-2}^8 xf(x)dx\\=60-I$$

hence solving for I we obtain,  $$I=\int_{-2}^8 xf(x)dx=30$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I:=\int_{-2}^8 x f(x)dx=-\int_8^{-2} (6-x) f(6-x)dx=\int_{-2}^8 (6-x) f(6-x)dx$$ so that

$$I+I=\int_{-2}^8 (x+6-x)f(6-x)dx=6\int_{-2}^8f(x)dx.$$